# fopen with the stdin as the filename parameter

Tags: c++, fopen, io-redirection

I was requested to write a program the basically parses the file given to it, with redirecting the stdin, like this:
myProg param1 param2 param3 < theFileToParse

I'm trying to use the fopen function in order to open the given file, but i don't understand what should i give it in the 'const char * filename' argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to open the file. Your program has a special value called `stdin` which contains a handle to the process's standard input stream. You can use this just as you would a file handle, for example:

```
int c = fgetc( stdin );
```

or:

```
fread( somebuffer, somesize, 1, stdin );
```

Comment: @Molly So use fread - you can use all the stream reading functions with stdin.

Answer (score 2):

You should not open anything at all, since stdin is **already** redirected, therefore you can simply use this stdin handle with standard file functions, i.e.:

```
while (fread(buf, 1, 1024, stdin) != 0) { // Read the data from input
  // Do something with data stored in buffer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use freopen.

From Unix man page:

```
#include < stdio.h >

     FILE *freopen(const char *filename, const char  *mode,  FILE
     *stream);
```